# How to clone Docusaurus showcase?

Tags: reactjs, docusaurus

I built a site with [Docusaurus](https://docusaurus.io). They have a really nice [showcase](https://docusaurus.io/showcase) page. I'd like to clone this and customize it for my own site (to serve as a portfolio of projects), but I'm not sure how to go about this.

I tried cloning the whole Docusaurus website (which is open source) and manually copying over the parts that seemed to be involved in the showcase page. But I keep getting stuck on basic errors like

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: React is not defined
```

despite having a React import statement.

I also considered rebuilding my site, starting from the cloned Docusaurus website (for which I can get the showcase to work when I run it locally). But the project is so huge and full of things that aren't relevant to my site that this doesn't seem like a good approach.

I would really appreciate any help with this! I'm not super experienced, so I may be making a really simple mistake. Does anyone have any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same idea, on the Docusaurus Showcase, you have two types of Websites, some with a Source button, and some without a Source button. Choose the ones with Source, download the source, install the docusaurus projet, search in the pages the item you want to understand or copy if allowed and improve your own Docusaurus project.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).